# FOR /F issue running from a text file

Tags: batch-file

I seem to experience an issue with the code underneath:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%a IN (logs\reachable.txt) do echo %%a && set ip=%%a && call :process


:process

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims=[]" %%i in (`ping -n 1 %ip%`) do set myip=%%i && set ip=
echo %myip%


call :end

:end
exit /b
```

The code is working fine but the last one in reachable.txt (ping) is displayed twice.

```
HOME
192.168.1.108
HIVE
192.168.1.100
HIVE-FS
192.168.1.110
Illusion-PC
::1
Ken-PC
192.168.1.20
192.168.1.20
```

Does anybody have an idea how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Illusion

Comment: Who voted to close this as off topic? I can only assume it was a language snob :-) People should realise that batch file programming is every bit as much programming as regular languages and this _is_ a scripting question, as evidenced by the `%%` in the variable names - simple stuff done from the command line would only have a single `%` (and also no labels either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because, once your first `for` loop is done, it's dropping through to the code beneath.

Replace:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%a IN (logs\reachable.txt) do echo %%a && set ip=%%a && call :process

:process
rem will be called from 'for' above AND when 'for' is done
```

with something like:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%a IN (logs\reachable.txt) do echo %%a && set ip=%%a && call :process
goto :eof

:process
rem will be called from 'for' above but NOT after 'for' is done
```

so that it *doesn't* drop through.

Comment: Thanks for your help, much apperciated.

Illusion